# Flag=1/0 based on multiple criteria on same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, case, aggregate-functions

I have a temp table that is being created, we will say that column 1 is YearMonth, column2 as user_id, Column 3 is Type.

```
YearMonth User_id   Type
200101    1         x
200101    2         y
200101    2         z
200102    1         x
200103    2         x
200103    2         p
200103    2         q
```

I want to count userids based on flag based on type. Hence I am trying to set flag to 1 and 0 but it always results in 0.

So for e.g. when the type contains x or y or z AND type contains P or Q then flag=1 by YearMonth.

I am trying something like

```
SELECT count (distinct t1.user_id) as count,
          t1.YearMonth,
          case when t1.type in ('x','y','z')
          and 
          t1.type in ('p','q') then 1 else 0 end as flag
      FROM table t1
      group by 2,3;
```

I would like to know why it doesn't give output as below:

```
count YearMonth Flag
0      200001    1
2      200001    0
1      200002    1
1      200002    0
```

What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: That `CASE` expression can *never* be true, when can `t1.type` have the the value `'x'`, `'y'`, or `'z'` **and** either `'p'` or `'q'`. Seems like you want some conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select yearmonth, flag, count(*) cnt
from (
    select yearmonth, id,
        case when max(case when t1.type in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 1 else 0 end) = 1
              and max(case when t1.type in ('p', 'q') then 1 else 0 end) = 1
            then 1 
            else 0 
        end as flag
    from mytable
    group by yearmonth, id
) t
group by yearmonth, flag
```

This first flags users for each month, using conditional aggregation, then aggregates by flag and month.

If you also want to display `0` for flags that do not appear for a given month, then you can generate the combinations with a `cross join` first, then brin the above resultset with a `left join`:

```
select y.yearmonth, f.flag, count(t.id) cnt
from (select distinct yearmonth from mytable) y
cross join (values (0), (1)) f(flag)
left join (
    select yearmonth, id,
        case when max(case when t1.type in ('x', 'y', 'z') then 1 else 0 end) = 1
              and max(case when t1.type in ('p', 'q') then 1 else 0 end) = 1
            then 1 
            else 0 
        end as flag
    from mytable
    group by yearmonth, id
) t on t.yearmonth = y.yearmonth and t.flag = f.flag
group by y.yearmonth, f.flag
```

Comment: With the sample data the OP gives us that doesn't give the results they ask for though. I had a similar solution, but the OP has both a `1` and `0` flag for both months.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82e810478181e2a151d6b5f5e10a3073) for both our attempts.

Answer (score 0):

I *thought* a very similar idea as GMB, however, like him, I don't get the expected results. Likely, however, we both are assuming the expected results are wrong:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) AS [Count],
       YearMonth,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] IN ('x','y','z') THEN 1 END) > 0
             AND COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] IN ('p','q') THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END AS Flag
FROM (VALUES(200101,1,'x'),
            (200101,2,'y'),
            (200101,2,'z'),
            (200102,1,'x'),
            (200103,2,'x'),
            (200103,2,'p'),
            (200103,2,'q')) V(YearMonth,UserID,[Type])
GROUP BY YearMonth;
```